# Give 10k users the ability to see the total count of flags they've handled

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, flags

I didn't find this neither by searching, nor among the suggestions when I was posting, so I think there are not duplicates. If I missed them, point me to them.

I'm a 10K user on EL&U, and now and then I help the mods clearing the flags or the reviews made by low-rep users.

As a mod on other sites, I can access the stats and see how many flags I've handled. However, this is not possible as a 10K user, as far as I can tell.

Unless I missed this too, can we make it so that 10K users can see the total count for the handled flags?

**Edit**: A note... When I see my flagging history, accessible from my profile, do I view only the flags I "sent" or also the ones I handled?

**Edit 2**: Following the request from the comments, when I flag a post for moderator attention, then **I'm flagging**. If, instead, some low-rep user flags posts and I dismiss them (as a mod/10K user) as helpful/declined, then **I'm handling** them.

I didn't invent this terminology, I used the term I saw by hovering the mouse cursor over my stats where I'm a moderator.

Comment: I follow the request, but the definition of "handled" is kind of wide. Define handle?

Comment: @waffles: Doesn't the review queue "know" when you've done something to a flagged post, so that the post won't show up again if you refresh the queue? That's what I imagined to be meant by "handled".

Comment: @waffles Sorry, I wasn't here before now. I added it to the question! :)

Comment: @Alenanno you handle a flag as a 10k user only as a side effect... eg: you "promote" a close flag to a close vote. you may also simply downvote a question with a flag ... etc.. you do not have the full range on mod options as a 10k user

Comment: @waffles If I'm not mistaken, only spam/comment flags are mod-only; while Low quality, Not an answer, etc, are handled by both... Is that correct? Just looking for confirmation.

Comment: @Alenanno **nothing** is handled directly by a single 10k user, they are handled by them as a side effect. So ... if you voted to delete a "not an answer" as a 20k user, the post is not deleted, the flag remains until the final delete vote is cast. If you vote to close a post with close votes, you "promote" the close flag and handle it as a side effect.

Comment: @waffles I see. I thought there was a sharing for the flag handling. :) So, summarizing: when I see the "flag-icon-number" above, as a 10K user, and I open it and I dismiss it as valid/invalid, I'm still "helping", if I understood what you said... Is this correct? If yes, I think my proposal would still be valid, as in, show me the total count of flags I've "helped mods to handle"...